# When I used "colSpan" in react, why doesn't it change what's on the dom?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to use colSpan in react

```
<th  colSpan="2" className="CustomerTableHead">
 Description
  </th>
```

I've tried colSpan={6} and colSpan='6' as other threads suggested but it isn't working. I'm very new at this and any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Possible create a code sandbox and share it here.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a HTML problem. Your code doesn't show the other rows and columns in your table, but at the very least you'll need two columns in subsequent rows in order to allow the colspan to appear correctly.

Here's a basic example of a Table component with a colSpan of 2:

```js
const Table = () => {
  return (
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <th colSpan="2" className="CustomerTableHead">
          Description
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

This shows as:

[image: Table with colSpan of 2]